# java web app указать где находяться ресурсы

Tags: java-ee, jsp, jstl, web.xml

1. Пишу простенькое приложение на голых сервлетах. Как и в каком файле указать где находяться статические ресурсы через xml-конфигурацию? (в спринге, например, в конфигурационном файле самого спринга нужно указать

```html
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/js/" />
```

2. нужно ли и как черз xml указать что мы используем jstl. К примеру в спринге в config указывал автозагрузку UrlBasedViewResolver'a:

   ```
   @Bean
   public UrlBasedViewResolver setupUrlBasedViewResolver(){
     UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
     viewResolver.setPrefix("/resources/pages/");
     viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
     viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
     viewResolver.setOrder(1);

     return viewResolver;
   }
   ```

   сервер - tomcat; собираю с помоощью maven; JQuery - есть скрипт на странице + сама библиотека лежит в отдельной папке - вот на ее то я и собираюсь ссылатьсе с ресурсов. СSS - просто лежат в отдельной папке + jsp-страницы хочу поместить в отдельные папки.

Comment: 1) а как вы эти ресурсы используете? 2) какой сервер используете?

Comment: у меня у меня есть JQuery, CSS  + я хочу страницы положить в отдельную папку page. Также я использую jstl tags. На Spring config я это делал, а вот с помощью xml-настроек пока что найти не могу...

Comment: как вы используете эти ресурсы? каким кодом? а на второй вопрос? и как вы собираете проект?

Comment: извиняюсь: сервер - tomcat; собираю с помоощью maven; JQuery - есть скрипт на странице + сама библиотека лежит в отдельной папке - вот на ее то я и собираюсь ссылатьсе с ресурсов. СSS - просто лежат в отдельной папке.

Comment: Ничего указывать не надо. Просто пусть лежат себе там же в WEB-INF/(js|css). Ответный html как генерится? через forward к jsp? В jsp на них можно ссылаться так `<script src="${request.contextPath}/js/jquery.js">`.

Comment: @Sergey Вы меня озадачили. Я новичек и думал, что достаточно просто написать JSP страницу и в web.xml указать mapping как для обычного сервлета, т.к. по турториалам я понял, что jsp страница - это и есть сервлет.  Но судя по всему я ошибся. В Spring MVC  это делается в контроллере, а на сервлетах как это правильно сделать подскажите?

Comment: Делать на сервлетах и на jsp - это немного разное. Сервлеты прописываются либо в web.xml, либо аннотациями. JSP автоматически распознаются сервером (и из них автоматически получаются сервлеты) и их не надо нигде прописывать. Ссылки такие же как на статические js, css, и пр. Кроме того jsp можно использовать как шаблон, чем spring и пользуется.

Comment: @Sergey Мой бок. Я делаю на JSP(и могу по необходимости использовать сервлет, например, для доступа к БД).  И передомною сейчас стоит вопрос: если у меня есть папка webapp (которая указана как web resource directory). В ней я все JSP страницы ложу в папку pages. Как мне сделать чтобы доступ к странице index шел по адресу site/index а не по адресу site/pages/index.jsp

Comment: Кстати, есть некоторые сомнения насчёт целесообразности изучения jsp в качестве самостоятельной платформы. Ведь эта техника смешивания html и кода всегда считалась плохой. В springe используется только возможность получить html по шаблону. В javaee настоятельно рекомендуется переобучиться на JSF. Так что сейчас имеет смысл осваивать только связку spring+jsp.

Comment: у меня по условиям задания стоит либо JSP либо Servlet. т.к. html кода много, то я склонился больше к jsp

Comment: @uncleSAM Доступ к БД можно получить и из JSP точно так же как из сервлета. Не кладите jsp в pages, а прямо в корень. Т.е. должно быть что-то такое `webapp/index.jsp` `webapp/js/jquery.js` `webapp/css/styles.css` jsp автоматически распознаются как jsp, остальное как статичный контент. Всё задумано так, чтобы было  просто. Прописи в спринге тоже имеют какую-то цель, но на самом примитивном уровне ничего такого не надо.

Comment: @Sergey дело в том, чтобы добраться до страницы мне нужно обязательно указывать ее разширение http://localhost:8080/index**.jsp** просто http://localhost:8080/index выдает 404. Неужели никак нельзя убрать суфикс в адресе? Спасибо, что приделили столько времени. Где можно поставить плюс?

Comment: Так это чтоли надо? <servlet>
      <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
      <jsp-file>index.jsp</jsp-file>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping> Т.е. в маппинге вмсето класса сервлета прописывается jsp-файл. Registering a JSP as a Servlet

Comment: @Sergey Это то, что я искал, но у меня почему то выдает ошибку org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]. Буду разбираться дальше. Спасибо!!